# NSSortDescriptors getting the right class comparison methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, nssortdescriptor

I am making a `NSFetchRequest` and want my results to come back sorted by date from `Core Data`. The `dateLastViewed` attribute is a `NSDate` in `Core Data` and so, I want my `compare:` method to be
that one of `NSDate`, right now it is the one in `NSNumber`... how do I set this?

```
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateLastViewed" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)]];
```

Comment: What do you mean by _the `compare:` method is the one in `NSNumber`_? Both classes (among many others) implement this method...

Comment: I assumes so since when i cmd clicked on it to bring up the documentation it showed me the compare: method for NSNumber

Comment: @TomLilletveit That's Xcode being idiotic.  The function is clearly defined for [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare:).

Comment: @TomLilletveit Oh... Now I get it. No worries, your code is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 2):

Core Data does the right thing when sorting by a date-valued property. You should be able to use a plain old `NSSortDescriptor` without specifying a comparator:

```
[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateLastViewed" ascending:YES]
```

You might be directed to the documentation for the `compare:` method on `NSNumber` when you search for it, but as noted by Alladdinian, many Foundation classes implement `compare:`, including `NSDate`.